# Qt QPSQL driver not loaded

Tags: qt

I am trying to load psql on qt without success. My code:

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");
MainWindow w;
w.show();
return a.exec();
```

I have QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS enabled. Output is:

> "The plugin 'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/plugins/sqldrivers/qsqlpsql.dll' uses incompatible Qt library. (Cannot mix debug and release libraries.)" 
>            not a plugin 
>   QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/plugins/sqldrivers/qsqlpsqld.dll" 
>   Got keys from plugin meta data ("QPSQL7", "QPSQL") 
>   QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "C:/build-Hello-Desktop_Qt_5_1_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug/debug/sqldrivers" ... 
>   loaded library "C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/plugins/sqldrivers/qsqlpsqld.dll" 
>   QLibraryPrivate::loadPlugin failed on "C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/plugins/sqldrivers/qsqlpsqld.dll" : "Cannot load library C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/plugins/sqldrivers/qsqlpsqld.dll: The specified module could not be found." 
>   QSqlDatabase: QPSQL driver not loaded
>   QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7

My configuration:

```
- Windows 7 Enterprise
- Qt Creator 2.8.1
- Qt 5.1.1
- Postgre 9.2
- C:\PostgreSQL\9.2\bin; C:\PostgreSQL\9.2\lib added to PATH
```

I have run dependency walker for the libpg.dll. Two missing dependencies:

- GPSVC.DLL
- IESHIMS.DLL

It seems that after these steps my effort is going to less organised "just-try-something...".

Comment: Maybe you must add some dynamic libraries (DLL in WIndows) in your app output directory/sqldrivers directory

Comment: I added GPSVC.DLL and IESHIMS.DLL to sqldrivers directory. No effect

Comment: Did you compile your Qt yourself?

Comment: No, I downloaded the ready made package

Comment: GPSVC.DLL and IESHIMS.DLL do not mind.

Comment: No, don't mind any dll, but qsqlpsql.dll and qsqlpsqld.dll. It is definitely a debug/release problem.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem. 
It is usually the fact that you're using 32-bit Qt with 64-bit Postgresql. 
I downloaded the 32-bit postgresql, changed the path(in Qt creator) to the 32-bit postgre libraries and everything worked flawlessly.

Using: 
Qt 5.2.0, 32bit (from SDK)
PostgreSQL 9.3(x86)

Answer (score 1):

The first error message more or less tells everything:

> The plugin 'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/plugins/sqldrivers/qsqlpsql.dll'
>   uses incompatible Qt library. (Cannot mix debug and release
>   libraries.)"

I suppose your program is compiled in debug mode, but you are missing Qt plugins, which where compiled in debug mode. How this happened, since you said you used are ready made package... No idea.

Try to compile your program in release mode. In .pro: `CONFIG+=release`.

Comment: Thanks for the proposal! Output is now as follows: QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/plugins/sqldrivers/qsqlpsql.dll" 
Got keys from plugin meta data ("QPSQL7", "QPSQL") 
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/plugins/sqldrivers/qsqlpsqld.dll" 
"The plugin 'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/plugins/sqldrivers/qsqlpsqld.dll' uses incompatible Qt library. (Cannot mix debug and release libraries.)" 
         not a plugin

Comment: QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "C:/build-Hello-Desktop_Qt_5_1_1_MinGW_32bit-Release/release/sqldrivers" ... 
loaded library "C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/plugins/sqldrivers/qsqlpsql.dll" 
QLibraryPrivate::loadPlugin failed on "C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/plugins/sqldrivers/qsqlpsql.dll" : "Cannot load library C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/plugins/sqldrivers/qsqlpsql.dll: The specified module could not be found."

Comment: QSqlDatabase: QPSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7

Comment: You still have parts, which try to load the debug lib (qsqlpsqld.dll), others load the relaese lib (qsqlpsql.dll). Mind the **d**. And as you can see, the qsqlpsql.dll **is** loaded now. Does your program consists of several parts? All must be release.

Comment: Actually now I am little bit lost because my project is the simplest possible. All the attempts to load psql are already presented on my problem description above

Comment: QT       += core gui sql

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Hello
TEMPLATE = app

CONFIG += release

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

Comment: Looks perfect. I am afraid this was it for me here. If I had this problem, I would fetch the postgres sources and compile them myself. I found this post: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/655. Looks exactly like your problem even though mysql is used there. The error message is misleading, if this is true. Then your postgres libs are incompatible with your mingw-qt libs.

Answer (score 0):

try to recompile the PostgreSQl dll